# Woocommerce permalink

Tags: woocommerce, product, permalinks

The issue is on Woocommerce permalink. I have added 7 menus to my woocomerce website, of which 5 of them contains the products, the others are HOME and CART. The problem is, I ain't aware of the permalink concept. Though, I tried to link my products to the respective page by  changing permalink as

Custom Structure : http://example.org/%product_cat%/

Category base : products

and it works fine for the 5 products in the menu, but the problem occurs with my CART menu.
When I click it shows

```
"Page not found! Something has gone wrong. Sorry about that!"
```

I tried with Woocommerce settings, where I couldn't find any option to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to go to Woocommerce setting and then on Checkout tab set the Cart page to your designated Cart Page that you created. (Same goes as your checkout page). Or try to go to permalink and save again.

Answer (score 0):

What is the link that shows in the browser when you get the "Page not found" error?

If you go to Woocommerce Settings > Checkout, you will see a section called Checkout Pages. Make sure you set your cart and checkout pages to the correct page and save it. If that does not fix your issue, go to Settings > Permalinks and click save. Test again.

You also want to make sure you update your theme and plugins. If none of these options work, please send the url that shows when you get the "page not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a special plugin as well as you can save time and quickly manage URL’s on your WooCommerce store.

In my opinion, the best plugin for managing links to the WooCommerce platform is the [WooCommerce Permalink Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/) by Premmerce that allows you to configure URL generation strategy for your store. I used almost all similar plugins, but I can confidently say that it’s the best solution in this area. This plugin is completely free and has a friendly interface. So you can use this tool without any skill.

I hope It will help to you!